# Variant of 3sum with 4 numbers in n^2*log(n) time?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, big-o

I am working on a project for an algorithms course I'm in and I'm completely at an impass. The assignment is to find all sets of 4 numbers in an array for which i+j=k+l in O(n^2*log(n)) time.

I know this is similar to the 3sum problem, where you have to find all the sets in an array for which i+j+k=0. We have discussed a solution to this problem in our lecture that solves it in O(n^2*log(n)) time by iterating through all unique pairs of 2 (n^2 time) and using a binary search on a sorted array to find a value that satisfies the problem (log(n) time).

However, I don't see how the problem with 4 numbers could be solved in this time. I think it's a safe guess that the log(n) in the complexity comes from a binary search, which i'll use for the last one. However, that would mean I have to iterate over all possible combinations of 3 in n^2 time, which I just don't think is possible.

I'm not looking for someone to do my work for me, but maybe if someone knows how this can be solved, they could give me a gentle tap in the right direction. Thanks.

Edit: it might also be helpful to note that I am required to solve this using sorting. Once I do that, I have to write another implementation that makes it faster using hashing, but I think I'll be able to do that just fine on my own. I just need to figure out how I can solve the problem with sorting first.

Comment: What If you parse the array and store each pair sum as key value in map. For example Map(key=(sum(pair)), value=pair location)
After parsing you can get the list which has key collisions :)

Comment: Are the numbers in array unique ? Can numbers ``i, j, k, l`` repeat ?

Comment: Yes, I am fairly certain that they are unique. The assignment does not explicitly state it, but I have not been able to find a duplicate in the example test files given

Comment: @amitmah I can't put them in a map, because the assignment specifically states I have to use arrays and sorting to solve the problem

Comment: Are the numbers constrained in range or type?  If the numbers and the sums are constrained to be 32-bit integers, and we have no memory restrictions, there are some nifty memory-intensive solutions.

Comment: I'm fairly certain they're all in the range of 32 bit integers... However, I'm worried that memory-intensive solutions may slow the program down and I suspect that when it's being graded there'll be points given for time as well as a cutoff where they just stop running my program and award no points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a sorted list of sums and pairs.  For instance, given the list

```
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 9, 82]
```

we will want to identify `1+9 = 2+8`

Identify the largest two numbers in the list, O**(N)**.  In this case, they're (82, 32), a sum of 114.  Allocate an array `pair_sum` of 114 locations; set all locations to null pointers.

Now iterate through the list for your i, j pairs.  For each pair, insert the two numbers as a tuple-value at index i+j.  When you get a collision at some index, you're done: you found a second pair-sum.

I'll outline this in some not-quite-pseudo code; you can translate to your favorite implementation language.

bank = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 9, 82]
size = length(bank)

```
// Find the two largest numbers and allocate the array ...
pair_sum = array[114], initialize to all nulls

for lo in 0:size-1
    for hi in lo+1:size
        sum = bank[lo] + bank[hi]
        if pair_sum[sum]
            // There is already a pair with that sum
            print pair_sum[sum], "and", bank[lo], bank[hi]
        else
            // Record new sum pair
            pair_sum[sum] = tuple(bank[lo], bank[hi])
```

This is **O(N^2)**, with bounded space dependent on the array values.

**If** you aren't allowed to use the sum as an index for practical reasons, I think you can adapt this to a binary search and insertion, giving you the **log(n)** component.

Comment: It was never stated that I couldn't use the sum as an index, but the integers used in the test cases provided were in hundreds of thousands, so I think it'd be best not to allocate an array that large. This answer really helps, though. I think with this I can figure out what I need to do.

Also, it's not really important but the loop given would be **O(n!)** wouldn't it? It'd be O(N^2) if you looped across the entire array in both loops.

Comment: "hundreds of thousands" is no big deal for modern computers: does it matter to overall performance if you chew up 4Mb of memory to reduce the time complexity?

Comment: Each loop runs within the range of 0:size (sum of the largest two numbers).  That makes the nested loops **O(size^2)**.